# Postgres, replace all integer values with NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I'm trying to replace all values in a column where the value is 0 with NULL

```
SELECT score
REPLACE(score, 0, ISNULL)
FROM kpis
WHERE score=0
```

or

```
SELECT score
REPLACE(score, 0, ISNULL)
FROM kpis
```

But I get a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REPLACE"
LINE 2: REPLACE(score, 0, ISNULL)
```

Comment: Use a `case` expression instead. (Also, REPLACE is for strings, not integers.)

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to just return NULL in the SELECT, or permanently change the values in the table (i.e. run an UPDATE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nullif()` which is functionally equivalent to a CASE expression, but a bit shorter to write.

```
SELECT nullif(score, 0) as score
FROM kpis
```

Answer (score 2):

**Replace all values in a column where the value is 0 with NULL**

```
update kpis set score = NULL where score = 0;
```

**Replace all integer values in a column with NULL**

```
update kpis set score = NULL where score ~ '^[0-9]*$'
```

Answer (score 1):

use case when

```
SELECT 
case when score = 0 then null else score end as score
from kpis
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replace you can use NULLIF(). Below query will set score=null when score is 0.

```
update kpis set score=NULLIF(score, 0)
```

Or you can simple use below query as suggested by @Sas.

`update kpis set score = NULL where score = 0;`

Comment: This is wrong. `coalesce()` returns the first non-null value, so your expression will always return the score or `0` - but never `NULL`

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have changed my answer. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Note that this will update the whole table, even if you aren't changing the score. Better is to apply a WHERE clause as in one of the other answers, at which point you don't need the NULLIF.